# Replicated SQL Server Database Deadlock Query Victim

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, deadlock

I have a replicated a SQL Sever 2008 R2 database setup and a query which runs hourly (taking about 3 minutes to run). This query populates a temporary table with its results.

However, every so often I get this error:

> Transaction (Process ID 63) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. [SQLSTATE 40001] (Error 1205)

This stops the query running.

What is the best practice for dealing with this error.

Thanks in advance.

> exec sp_executesql N'EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_sqlagent_log_jobhistory @job_id = @P1, @step_id = @P2, @sql_message_id = @P3, @sql_severity = @P4, @run_status = @P5, @run_date = @P6, @run_time = @P7, @run_duration = @P8, @operator_id_emailed = @P9, @operator_id_netsent = @P10, @operator_id_paged = @P11, @retries_attempted = @P12, @session_id = @P13, @message = @P14',N'@P1 uniqueidentifier,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 int,@P8 int,@P9 int,@P10 int,@P11 int,@P12 int,@P13 int,@P14 nvarchar(4000)','0A7AFD76-D2EC-463E-A802-8B66241B0D26',2,8153,13,0,20140320,110114,219,0,0,0,0,52,N'Executed as user: DOMAIN\sql. Transaction (Process ID 62) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. [SQLSTATE 40001] (Error 1205)  Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation. [SQLSTATE 01003] (Error 8153).  The step failed.'

Above is the return form Profiler.

Comment: Are there any other jobs modifying the tables your query is accessing?

Comment: @shree.pat18 the only thing I can suggest is the replication itself?

Answer (score 2):

You need to investigate what is causing the deadlock. The solution will depend entirely on what you find. some reads on the subject:

- [Analyze Deadlocks with SQL Server Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188246.aspx)
- [Save Deadlock Graphs (SQL Server Profiler)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190465.aspx)
- [How To Monitor Deadlocks in SQL Server](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2012/06/28/how_2d00_to_2d00_monitor_2d00_deadlocks_2d00_in_2d00_sql_2d00_server.aspx)
- [Deadlock Troubleshooting, Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2006/09/09/747119.aspx)
- [Troubleshooting deadlocks in SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/05/617960.aspx)

Note that if you scan a table while is being updated deadlocks are *very* likely. A '3 minute' query over data actively modified by replication agents would likely be exactly such case. Ideally your query should be optimized to read only the relevant data (eg. what changed since last read). A cheap way out is to enable versioning in the database, read [Implementing Snapshot or Read Committed Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server: A Guide](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/):

```
ALTER DATABASE <dbname> SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
```

Comment: Im 99% certain it is the replication, what I didnt mention is that the deadlock is occuring on the subscription database not the publisher (I dont know if this helps).

Comment: Is completely irrelevant. A deadlock is a deadlocks is a deadlock. Read the articles linked. Capture the deadlock graph.